# Headless Chrome Puppeteer Skip Logging In To Twitter Using Cookies?

Tags: cookies, twitter, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Is it possible to skip logging in to twitter by setting cookies?

I tried to copy an paste what I got from "document.cookie" in web console but that gave me the error `Invalid parameters name: string value expected`

```
await page.setCookie({
    personalization_id: "v1_VDBAhQo+RMCSceKUBXfs3w==",
    guest_id: "v1%3A150575165219105300",
    ct0: "d9343a3b062832b6ec23a84747e518b3",
    _gat: "1m",
    ads_prefs: "HBERAAA=",
    remember_checked_on: 1,
    twid: "u=908918507005456384",
    lang: "en",
    tip_nightmode: true,
    _ga: "GA1.2.1275876041.1505751657",
    _gid: "GA1.2.1311587009.1505751657"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for [`setCookie`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies) is not what you used, it's:

```
setCookie(cookie1, cookie2, ...)
```

where `cookie` is an object containing `name` and `value` keys, like

```
setCookie({name: 'lang', value: 'en'})
```

Remember to set the cookies before loading Twitter, or to reload the page after setting them, and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function addCookies(cookies_str, page, domain){
    let cookies = cookies_str.split(';').map(pair=>{
        let name = pair.trim().slice(0,pair.trim().indexOf('='))
        let value = pair.trim().slice(pair.trim().indexOf('=')+1)
        return {name,value,domain}
    });
    await Promise.all(cookies.map((pair)=>{
        return page.setCookie(pair);
    }))
}
```

this is my way to add cookies, cookies_str was copied from browser;